# his justifying mistake or his justifying of mistake

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

(1) I can't understand the student's justifying the mistake.

(2) I can't understand the student's justifying of the mistake.

Which sentence is correct?   Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: The preposition is not needed here. (1) "I can't understand the student's justifying the mistake." Please see also [ell.se]. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

They are both correct, but they are parsed differently - in the first sentence *'s* is short for *is*, in the second sentence *'s* is the possessive.

That means the two sentences can be paraphrased as:

> (1) I can't understand (why) the student is justifying the mistake.
>   (2) I can't understand the justifying (by the student) of the mistake.

Comment: It's possessive in both.

Comment: @Kris if it's possessive in the first sentence, how do you parse that sentence? I would expect there to be an _of_ in between _justifying_ and _the mistake_. Or, the other way around, why can the first sentence not be read as _the student is_? Or, would you argue that in _I hear the car's honking the horn_ , the _'s_ is possessive? And in _I understand the plane's crashing, please hand me a parachute?_

Comment: If it were a positive sentence then I think you could interpret it either way. For example, in "I understand the plane's crashing" the 's can be possessive (the crashing of the plane is something that I understand) or it can stand for "is" (I understand that the plane is crashing). For me, when you make it a negative sentence, it's hard to "feel" the second version. I'm not quite sure what "I don't understand that the plane is crashing" would mean, whereas "The crashing of the plane is something that I don't understand" is, err, something that I do understand.

Comment: @Rupe I'm not sure what goes wrong in that sentence. If you look at what happened to [Air France flight 447](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447) it seems clear that for quite some time the pilots _didn't understand the plane was crashing_. Or they didn't understand the pitot tubes were failing_.

Comment: "They didn't understand that the plane was crashing" is fine. Changing it to the first person, present tense, makes all the difference. "I am not aware of that thing"... it's kind of paradoxical.

Comment: @Rupe: in the sense of _being aware of_, it is indeed a bit strange. But in the common sense of _understanding_, I don't see the problem, as in the sentence _I cannot understand (why) the student is complaining_, or _I cannot understand (why) he is not being honest to her_, meaning _The student is complaining, but it makes no sense to me_, or _he is lying to her, but it doesn't make sense to me_ - I can't understand why they do that. Does the same problem persist if I would change it to _I can't **believe** the student is justifying the mistake_?